# I'm just starting with jmathplot and I got this exception message

Tags: java, jmathplot

I want to plot a **graph** in my **application** so I downloaded `jmathplot.jar` and added it to my project.

When I add a field to my Frame:

```
private PlotPanel plot = new Plot2DPanel();
```

I get a nasty long exception message at compile:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  org/math/io/StringPrintable
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at org.math.plot.canvas.PlotCanvas.(PlotCanvas.java:491)
>           at org.math.plot.canvas.Plot2DCanvas.(Plot2DCanvas.java:25)
>           at org.math.plot.Plot2DPanel.(Plot2DPanel.java:47)
>           at Frame1.initialize(Frame1.java:39)
>           at Frame1.(Frame1.java:31)
>           at Frame1$1.run(Frame1.java:18)
>           at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.math.io.StringPrintable
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           ... 32 more

What is happening?

**EDIT**

OK. I imported `jmathio.jar`. Now I got the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.math.plot.components.PlotToolBar.<init>(PlotToolBar.java:61)
    at org.math.plot.PlotPanel.addPlotToolBar(PlotPanel.java:149)
    at org.math.plot.PlotPanel.<init>(PlotPanel.java:59)
    at org.math.plot.PlotPanel.<init>(PlotPanel.java:67)
    at org.math.plot.Plot2DPanel.<init>(Plot2DPanel.java:31)
    at Frame1.<init>(Frame1.java:10)
    at Frame1$1.run(Frame1.java:19)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to include 
    https://github.com/yannrichet/jmathio/blob/master/dist/jmathio.jar jar in your classpath. `jmathplot.jar` depends on `jmathio.jar`. so download this and put it in your classpath and it should work

Comment: you can check out the more info here https://github.com/yannrichet/jmathplot/issues/16